# Bash scripts have strange special characters in them

Tags: linux, bash, shell, special-characters

I am storing bash scripts onto a CentOS server from `PHP` over `SSH2`; I know it is complicated, but just bear with me.

When I open up the file (on the server):

```
vi myScript
```

I see:

```
ls -al^M
free -m
```

So, when I try an execute it with:

```
bash myScript
```

The output throws an error:

```
ls: invalid option -- 
Try `ls --help' for more information.
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           676        642         34          0         33        313
-/+ buffers/cache:        295        380
Swap:          767          1        766
```

What is the `^M` and any idea where it is coming from? The bash script should to be able to support newlines and tabs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

^M is end of line coming from Windows. The file was created in Windows initially. You may do in vi something like :1,$ s/^v^M//g to delete those.

Also you can use `dos2unix` command on the entire file to clean it in one shot. You can do it before execution of script.

Comment: It it not coming from windows though. It is being generated in PHP, and written to the server from PHP using ssh2.

Comment: It's hard to tell for sure what happened. But typically something would be processing the file on Windows to cause those ^M

Comment: What is OS where PHP is running? Also is generation driven by some text input from browser? It's possible that PHP just uses the same end of lines as in input it received.

Comment: The content of the bash script, is edited in a web interface, a textarea on a Mac. Would that generate the `^M` characters? PHP is running on Linux.

Comment: I would not expect that. But I don't know enough about mac. Also you can use dos2unix command to get rid of those.

Comment: I'd like to do the clean-up, before writing them to the server, is there a way I can remove them in `PHP` before writing them to the server?

Comment: @Justin HTML text areas [*should*] submit \r\n (the internet "standard") for newlines. Normalize this on the server by replacing all \r\n with \n.

Comment: I'd first determine which step in the process causes it.

Comment: @pst good point. I didn't realize that. If so, I'd say PHP should use some simple replacement to clean up. But I don't know PHP.

Comment: @pst, so all modern (Chrome, FireFox, Safari) browsers write `\r\n`. Can I simply do a string replace of `\r\n` with `\n`?

Answer (score 3):

The `^M` is the CR or carriage return character.  Somewhere along the line, your code got contaminated with CRLF line endings, commonly found on Windows machines.  Also, many internet protocols use CRLF line endings.

To fix, edit the file in `vim` and use `:set fileformat=unix`; if you do `:set` or `:set all` before changing it to `unix`, you should see `fileformat=dos` instead.  Then save the file.

The CR messes up backslashes at the end of the line because the backslashes aren't at the end of the line any more; they're followed by the carriage return, which is not a newline.